# what is unchecked cast warning and what java expects to do in this case

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am `C/C++` programmer and new to java. I have the following code(a part of XML RPC server/client application) and when complied with `-Xlint` option I get a warning.

*Code:*

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:8081"));
config.setEnabledForExceptions(true);
config.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setConfig(config);
Object[] params = new Object[0];
//execute returns java.lang.Object . getProcInfo has return type ArrayList<ProcInfo> 
ArrayList<ProcInfo> list = (ArrayList<ProcInfo>)client.execute(config,"test.getProcInfo", params);
```

*Warning:*

`warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast`

What I do not understand is why there is a warning in the first place. Why there arises a need to check it when I am casting it to the same object I am returning from other function and let us say that even if there is a need then can this checking not done by the compiler itself.

How can I fix this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unchecked cast warning means that due to Java's type erasure (generic type parameters do not exist at runtime and therefore cannot be checked when casting) even if the cast succeeds, one does not know whether the type actually matches the declared generic type.

To eliminate this circumstance, instead of casting to `ArrayList<ProcInfo>` cast to:

```
List<?> list = (List<?>)client.execute(config,"test.getProcInfo", params);
```

This denotes the type "Some list implementation with some element type". Then, when accessing elements of the list, cast them to `ProcInfo`:

```
for(Object element : list){
  final ProcInfo info = (ProcInfo) element;
  // do something with info
}
```

Neither cast will then cause a warning.

Comment: Can I do normal accessing of data members and functions inside the `ProcInfo` class if I use this approach

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Yes, all public members and functions will be accessible as usual. I added an example of how list iteration would look like in this case.

Comment: I am just confused that why this cast will not cause a warning.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam The warning means that even if the cast succeeds at runtime, you may not get the type declared, because runtime casts cannot check type parameters (A cast to a List doesn't look into the list and checks whether all elements are of type `ProcInfo`). Making all casts explicit (only cast one object at a time) makes the compiler happy.

Answer (score 3):

Unchecked cast warning means, you are trying to cast from raw type to generic type.

Your `execute` method returning Object, but you are casting to `ArrayList<ProcInfo>` which is of generic type, so compiler warning you that  return type of execute is not what you are expecting.

Two ways you can overcome this warning (I know of):

1) Add `@SuppressWarnings` [annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)

2) Remove generictype from ArrayList.

These methods will eliminate the compiler error.

Comment: "compiler warns you that if cast is not appropriate you may see ClassCastException at runtime.". No, the warning is for heap pollution, that is, you might be casting an ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<ProcInfo>, *without* a ClassCastException (because the VM does not have generics at runtime).

Comment: @Bohemian: If there is no generics here, you will see compile time error, isn't it? And your answer explicitly telling this is because you are expecting ProcInfo of type, which is generic.

Comment: @Bohemian, all warnings tagged with `[unchecked]` (and only those) are the generic-related warnings.

Comment: @ignis: After reading your comment couple of times, it makes sense. Deleted non-applicable words from answer, because generics are erased, it might make sense just till point of ArrayList creation. At runtime when OP tries to iterate list, it would still cause ClassCastException if types doesn't match.

Comment: @Nambari Can you please explain what is meant by "Remove generictype from ArrayList"

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: That means, instead of typing ArrayList<ProcInfo> just ArrayList. If you are using java1.5 or higher I wouldn't advise using this approach. When you are <sometype> it will be called as generics.

Comment: @Nambari, the warning has nothing to do with Object vs ArrayList, it's the cast that plays the role of the warning for that matter. The cast means: CCE if raw types do not match. The warning means: no CCE if generic types do not match.

Comment: @Nambari: so I have to use `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. Is that the only option.

Comment: @Ignis: Yeah, that is what I meant too. May be way of wording is different.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: If you are sure that return type would be ArrayList<ProcInfo>, I would suggest go with SuppressWarning.

Comment: @ignis You said that "you might be casting an ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<ProcInfo>". What I am trying to understand is that the compiler has the methods's return type information at compile time. So why does the compiler does not check that there is a mismatch at compile time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam, right, and the return type information is Object. The compiler won't look inside the method.

Comment: Your two options are not the only options, see my answer.

Comment: @ignis: i missed that point. The casting has been done internally earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore the warning and are sure it's safe, write @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") above the line giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `execute()` method return type is `Object`, but you are casting it to the more specific type `ArrayList<ProcInfo>`. The compiler is warning you that there is no guarantee bass on the method signature that it will in fact be an object of the type to are casting to.

If you are confident that the implementation will return the type you're expecting, you can tell the compiler to not issue a warning by adding this annotation to the method in which the cast is being made:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Comment: I do not want to suppress warning. I want to remove it in this scenario. How is that possible

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam, it suppresses the warning only in that method - not project-wide.

Comment: It is not possible to remove it because the execute method is untyped